# addition of values of variable and convert into hexadecimal in shell script

Tags: shell, sh

in a shell script
I have a number of series

```
11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
(8 4 2 1,8 4 2 1,8 4 2 1) on this bases 
the maximum value is "f"
```

so if i give value

```
variable=3,2,1
```

it should return (0,0,8+4+2=14 means e )

```
e
0e
00e
```

if i give value(0 ,8+4+2=14 means e,0)

```
varible=8,7,6
```

it should return

```
e0
0e0
```

if i give value

```
varible=11,10,9
```

it should return(8+4+2=14 means e,0,0)

```
e00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk -v RS=, '{s+=$1} END{printf "%02x\n", s}' <<< "$variable"
0e
```

**EDIT:** If not using bash then:

```
echo "$variable" | awk -v RS=, '{s+=$1} END{printf "%02x\n", s}'
0e
```

Comment: /bin/sh -version GNU sh, version 1.14.7(1)

Comment: You can do: `echo "$variable" | awk -v RS=, '{s+=$1} END{printf "%02x\n", s}'`

Comment: ya this one is working, can you tell me answer of edited question ?

Comment: Edited part of your question is little confusing. `0xe0` is `224` in decimal.

Comment: its in series (8 4 2 1, 8 4 2 1,8 4 2 1) like binary numbers... now this 11,10,9  falls in left series  so 8+4+2 = 14 and hex format of 14 is "e", and with other two series there is no value in this addition so it becomes 0.

Comment: now if I select `varible=11,10,1`   it would be  8+4 =12 , 0 ,1  means final answer would be `c01`

Comment: I am sorry I tried to understand this series maths many times but I am unable to comprehend it. Besides I can see that nature of this question has completely changed, from summing and converting to hex now it is about building some strange maths series. I would sincerely advise you to post a new question with this maths series problem so that you get better answers. If you wish you can mark this once as accepted since it answered your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter expansion to replace commas with pluses. Then, use arithmetic expansion to do the calculation. Finally, use `printf` to do the conversion and format the output:

```
printf '%03x\n' $(( ${variable//,/+} ))
```

Comment: /bin/sh -version
GNU sh, version 1.14.7(1)

Comment: ${variable//,/+} : bad substitution
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @user95711: Why the `bash` tag, then?

Comment: @user95711: What is the bash version?

Comment: echo $BASH_VERSION
1.14.7(1)

Comment: @user95711: It's from 1998 :-o